# Converting an Eigen::VectorXd to an std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

As the title says, I am trying to convert an Eigen::VectorXd to an std::vector. The vector is obtained by diagonalizing a matrix and then taking the first eigenvector of the process.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> vec;
    MatrixXd ones = MatrixXd::Ones(3,3);
    VectorXd firstEvector;
    SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> es(ones);
    firstEvector = es.eigenvectors().col(1);
    cout << "The first eigenvector of the 3x3 matrix of ones is:" << endl << firstEvector << endl;
    vec(&firstEvector[0], firstEvector.data() + firstEvector.cols()*firstEvector.rows());
    return 0;
}
```

I thought this was the way to do it, however, it doesn't work. I get the following error.

```
C:\CBProjects\eigenVectors\main.cpp|20|error: no match for call to '(std::vector<double>) (Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>, 1>::Scalar*, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >::Scalar*)'|
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a constructor syntax for the `std::vector` `vec` although the vector was already declared. That doesn't work.

There are two efficient possibilities to copy the content of an `Eigen::VectorXd` into a `std::vector<double>`. You can either construct a new `std::vector` `vec2`, like this:

```
vector<double> vec2(firstEvector.data(), firstEvector.data() + firstEvector.size());
```

or use the previously declared vector `vec` and transfer the data from the `Eigen::VectorXd` by using `Eigen::Map`. But in that case the `std::vector` first needs to be resized:

```
vec.resize(firstEvector.size());
Map<VectorXd>(vec.data(), vec.size()) = firstEvector;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow this is really helpful! Not sure why it does not have more upvotes!